# Appending missing months in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a following `df`:

```
df
               A                     B                   C
January        209733                0                   0
February       223054                0                   0
March          127957                0                   0
April          67021                 0                   0
```

I would like to add the missing months as empty cells to this `df`. In order to do so, I created an `df_empty`:

```
df_empty = {'A': '', 'B': '', 'C': ''}
```

And I want to `pd.concat` it to my original `df` via:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df_empty, index=['May', 'June', 'July', ...])])
```

However I don't want to hard code all the months, instead it should be recognised that the last month in the `df` is `'April'`, and fill the `index=[]`, according to other missing months.

Here is the index of the `df`:

```
df.index
Index(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'], dtype='object')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: by "*missing months*" you mean to fill a whole year?

Comment: yes. Basically list of months in string after the df.index[-1] to end of the year which is December

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the missing months via:

```
missing_months = [i for i in range(dt.datetime.strptime(df.index[-1], '%B').month+1, 13)]
```

Then convert them to month names with a for-loop, and save it in the list:

```
for i in range(len(missing_months)):
    missing_months[i] = dt.date(1900, missing_months[i], 1).strftime('%B')
```

Lastly `missing_months` list can be use in `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
idx = pd.date_range(start="1950-01", freq="M", periods=12)
df = df.reindex(idx.month_name()).fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                A  B  C
January    209733  0  0
February   223054  0  0
March      127957  0  0
April       67021  0  0
May                    
June                   
July                   
August                 
September              
October                
November               
December
```